# How to pass a variable as the key for the Map.get method?

Tags: apex, map, key

I know that to get the value of a map, i should use:

```
String s = (String)Map.get('key');
```

The above code works fine. But, I want **a variable to be passed as the key**. I tried like this:

```
String k = 'key';
String s = (String)Map.get(k);
```

But, this returns null. So, my question is there any other way to do this or is it not possible?

Comment: What you have should work just fine (and you likely don't need to do the explicit type-casting, unless your map is a `Map<String, Object>`). Showing us your actual code (and showing us how the map is populated, or at the very least the keys & values stored in it just before you try to use `.get()`) would help here. About the only thing I can think of given the current information is to tell you that map keys are _case sensitive_.

Comment: @DerekF yeah. that was the problem. I am getting data from the database. The retrieved key is first letter capital, but the key I passed was full small letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not clear from the paraphrsaed code, the issue here is one of case sensitivity.

Map keys (and values stored in Sets) are *case sensitive*.

Given this map

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new Map<String, Integer>{'keyval1' => 1};
```

`myMap.get('Keyval1')` would return null because "Keyval1" != "keyval1" in this specific context. General string comparison in Apex is not case-sensitive, but we're not doing string comparison when we call `.get()` on a map. Instead, the key is being hashed, and the resulting hash is used to grab the value from the map.

#### One more thing

There is one other sitution that comes to mind here, emails. Salesforce transforms data stored in email fields to be all lower case (once you re-query for it). So this case sensitivity issue can also pop up if you're getting mixed-case (or all upper case) email from a form or external system.